# magento 2 subtotal mismatch in minicart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have used the `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event in magento2, I am able to set the custom price in the mini-cart after add to cart. but my subtotal showing mismatch.

[image]

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_after">
     <observer name="Demo_Customprice" instance="Demo\Customprice\Observer\SalesQuoteCollectTotalsPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**SalesQuoteCollectTotalsPrice.php**

```
<?php
  namespace Demo\Customprice\Observer;
  use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
  class SalesQuoteCollectTotalsPrice implements ObserverInterface
  {

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
   $quote = $observer->getQuote();
   $cartItems=$quote->getAllVisibleItems();
   foreach($cartItems as $item )
   {
      $finalCustomprice="163.47";//Customized price want to set here 
      $item->setCustomPrice($finalCustomprice);
      $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalCustomprice);
      $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

   }

}   }
```

this is my code could you please check and give me suggestions.

whether I can able to set the subtotal for single and multiple items?

Thanks

Comment: You nee to add three event catalog_product_get_final_price, checkout_cart_product_add_after, checkout_cart_product_update_after do same work

Comment: thanks for the updating nikhil i would like to know checkout_cart_product_add_after event which is useful for both 'add to cart' and 'update cart' ?